# spring rabbit and spring transactions

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have a spring rabbit consumer like:

```
@Override public void onMessage(Message amqpMessage, Channel channel)
            throws Exception {
//..some code goes here - I want it to be in spring transaction
}
```

The issue is the code which is in onMessage method is not under transaction. I checked it, I save data to 3 tables, then throw exception, then save to 4th table. And data from 3 previos tables is not being rolled back. How to do that properly in spring? I want all code in onMessage method to be within a transaction. Thanks

**UPDATE**
My rabbit conf:

```
@Configuration @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.mycompany"})
public class TicketModeRabbit {
    @Bean TicketModeConsumer ticketModeConsumer() {
        return new TicketModeConsumer();
    }

    @Bean(name = TicketModeRabbitData.QUEUE_BEAN_NAME) Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(TicketModeRabbitData.QUEUE_BEAN_NAME);
    }


    @Bean(name = TicketModeRabbitData.QUEUE_BINDING_NAME) Binding binding(
            @Qualifier(TicketModeRabbitData.QUEUE_BEAN_NAME) Queue q, TopicExchange e) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(q).to(e).with(TicketModeRabbitData.QUEUE_TOKEN_NAME);
    }

    @Bean(name = TicketModeRabbitData.CONTAINER_NAME)
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            @Qualifier(TicketModeRabbitData.LISTENER_ADAPTED_NAME)
                    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
        return WorkerConfigHelper
                .rabbitConfigListenerContainer(connectionFactory, listenerAdapter,
                        TicketModeRabbitData.QUEUE_BEAN_NAME,
                        WorkerConfigHelper.GLOBAL_CONCURRENT_CONSUMERS);
    }

    @Bean(name = TicketModeRabbitData.LISTENER_ADAPTED_NAME)
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter() {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(ticketModeConsumer());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your transaction manager is properly set up for your database, the only thing you need to do is add the `@Transactiona`l annotation on the `onMessage` method. Note that the consumer (`MessageListener`) needs to be a bean managed by the `Spring` container.

```
@Override 
@Transactional
public void onMessage(Message amqpMessage, Channel channel)
            throws Exception {
    //..some code goes here - I want it to be in spring transaction
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how to set up spring support for rabbit consumer? Thanks

Comment: How did you setup the MessageListener on the ListenerContainer? Can you add your spring configuration?

Comment: Thank you, I have just added it in my initilal post.

Comment: Your consumer is already a bean, adding the @Transactional annotation should be enough. You already have a TransactionManager for your DB?

Comment: Thank you, yes I have already set it up, strange why it doesn't work

Comment: When I set @Transactional, I get exception:

Comment: @Bean method TicketModeRabbit.ticketModeConsumer called as a bean reference for type [com.mycompany.consumers.ticket.TicketModeConsumer] but overridden by non-compatible bean instance of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74]. Overriding bean of same name declared

Comment: I think enable autoproxy should be set

Comment: It is because the ticketModeConsumer method annotated with @Bean must return a MessageListener instead of the concrete class (TicketModeConsumer). Spring is using the JDK proxy by default, which is based on the interface. You don't need EnableAspectJAutoProxy.